# get data from .dat file with python

Tags: python, database

I need to read a .dat file in python, i need to read two value from dat file

```
[Registration information]
Name=nikam
Key=**KDWOE**
```

need to get **nilkam** from name and **KDWOE** from key

```
    datContent = [i.strip().split() for i in open("./license.dat").readlines()]
        print (datContent)
```

i got this result
[['[Registration', 'information]'], ['Name=nilkam'], ['Key=KZOiX=BFcjLKqJr6HwYxYU+NHN8+MP7VO0YA5+O1PwX0C3twCmum=BLfBI95NQw']]
and from second

```
    with open("./license.dat", 'r') as f :
              f = (f.read())
        print (f)

i got this

[Registration information]
Name=nikam
Key=KDWOE
```

i need result **need to get nilkam from name and KDWOE from key**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what a `.dat` file is, and you don't specify, but given your example it looks like the [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) library might work for you.

```py
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('./license.dat')

print(config['Registration information']['Name'])
print(config['Registration information']['Key'])
```